# is it possible not giving the update access of record in S2S

Tags: standard-objects, salesforce2salesforce

I have read about Salesforce to Salesforce. I saw records are shared in a connection. 
**I dont want to see any kind of changes in records in published org made by other suscribe org**. Is it possible to put a constraint on S2S that subscribed cant modify the records of published org ??

Comment: Can you describe a specific scenario which you're envisioning with this constrained access? It seems that what you are asking is whether or not the data received from the publishing org can be read-only in the subscriber's org. Is that accurate?

Comment: sorry the query is very old but want to know.what u describe @MarkPond i am asking the same as you guess in your comment .

Answer (score 3):

By default the records which are copied from the source org (publisher) to the target org (subscriber) are owned by the connection user defined within the S2S configuration in the target org.

The target org is responsible for determining and granting access to these copied records as well as changing ownership of them as necessary.

The sharing model that is defined in the target org will determine which users and groups have access to its records. Unless the sharing model in the target org is simple and can be defined using configuration features, access to these S2S records will probably need to be granted using [Apex Managed Sharing](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) in the target org.

There are quite a few mechanisms available in Salesforce to make records read-only (sharing rules, page layouts, etc.), one of them will probably fit your use case.